# Задача Python, и точная кратность 7

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Решаю задачки, тут проблемка, не понимаю решение задачки, мне говорят что я близко, но всё таки нет. Сама задача:
Напишите сценарий, который печатает числа, кратные 7, от 0 до 100. Печатайте по одному кратному числу в каждой строке и избегайте печати любых чисел, не кратных 7. Помните, что 0 также является кратным 7.(`Вопрос 4 Write a script that prints the multiples of 7 between 0 and 100. Print one multiple per line and avoid printing any numbers that aren't multiples of 7. Remember that 0 is also a multiple of 7.`)

Я решаю:

```
for x in range(0,100):
    print(x**3)
```

Но мне отвечают:
Не совсем. Помните, что 0 делится на все числа. (`Not quite. Remember that 0 is a multiple of all numbers.`)
(Задачи на Английском, перевожу через Гугл переводчик)
Что прикажете делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Более питонический способ такой:

```
for i in range(0, 100, 7):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*[i for i in range(0, 100, 7)], sep='\n')
print(*[i for i in range(0, 100) if i % 7 == 0], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    print(i)
    i += 7
```